# How can I prevent people from copying and pasting my (python) program to others?

Tags: python, key, installation

I've finished working on a python program and I'd like to sell it; that said, how can I make it so that my program can't simply be copied and pasted all over the place? Obfuscating the code isn't what I'm looking for, I'm okay with .pyc, but how can I make my program more like - well - an actual paid program and work only if the person bought it?

Maybe an installer with a key?

Comment: Other than that, use a software license.

Comment: Check out PyInstaller. Also if you want to sell it without people copying it for sure try checking out close sourcing. If you ever, ever, ever sell anything online please get a license, some are free some aren't.

Comment: there are people willing to pay, and others, that aren't. forget the second ones and concentrate on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate some mechanism to lock down an installation to one computer.  Your program will have to interact with it. These schemes aren't foolproof.  Usually, they'll be tied to:

- the existence of a hardware dongle
- the processor type
- the volume name(s) on the hard disk
- the BIOS type
- other installed hardware (sound card, video, etc)

The idea is that the installer will create a "key" from the current computer hardware that won't work if the program is copied to another computer.

Look up "python license key generator" on Google for starters.

Comment: All those mechanisms are based on code obfuscation.